# Python Imports Not Working with Directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am having trouble importing python modules in a different folder than the one I am using. I know there are a number of posts about this on StackOverflow, but I am still running into a few issues with importing. Here is my general file structure:

```
Folder
   __init__.py
   A.py
   folder
      __init__.py
      B.py
   tests
      __init__.py
      C.ipynb
```

I am trying to import B from C, but doing so gives me a number of errors. If I write

```
from folder import B
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'.
```

If I write

```
from . import B
```

I get

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
```

If I write

```
from . import B
```

or

```
from .. import B
```

I get

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.
```

Additionally, if I try to import B from A, I also get errors. Running

```
import folder.B
```

or
from folder import B
gives

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'.
```

Could someone help me import these files correctly? I know that modifying sys.path is an option (although I am not entirely sure how to implement this), but I feel like there must be a way to do this without modifying sys.path.

Thank you, and I apologize if this has been answered already!

Comment: You've discovered the pain that is python relative imports. IMO, the best way would just be modifying sys.path.

Comment: @SuperStormer No, just leave `sys.path` alone. Instead, don't try running a notebook *inside* a package.

Comment: You could try importing from `Folder` for example `from Folder.folder import B`

Comment: Are you try to run `C.ipynb` as a notebook? Don't do that *inside* a package. Move the notebook *outside* of the package when running it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I will probably just move C. The only problem is that I am trying to make a package and it seems standard to keep the tests in a folder like the test folder above?